# Error with input-validation using std::cin

Tags: c++, validation, user-input, iostream

I have implemented this check in my program to determine if the input is of the right type or not, and if not it asks to re-write the input.
If the input is wrong it works just fine but, if the input is right, you need to write it again. How can I avoid this? (you can find an example here https://godbolt.org/z/KjoTbc)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {

int input;
std::cin >> input ;
while (!(std::cin >> input)) { 
std::cin.clear(); 
std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
std::cout << "Please, write an integer number\n"; 
};
}
```

Comment: Considering that you have two `cin >> input` statements it's not surprising that it asks you for input twice. Have you just tried removing the first `cin >> input`? It's not clear what it's doing there.

Comment: Yes, the answer below was satisfying, I'm sorry but I can't flag this as solved yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not checking the first `std::cin >> input ;` and running `while (!(std::cin >> input))`, which asks input, unconditionally.

Remove the first unchecked reading and try this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits>

int main() {

    int input;
    while (!(std::cin >> input)) { 
        std::cin.clear(); 
        std::cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(), '\n');
        std::cout << "Please, write an integer number\n"; 
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok, it works. Is there a way to implement this same process with another condition inside the `while()` cycle? I think it would be more readable.